# Loading a partial view from another project using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, ninject

Ok, so I have some UserControls that I am trying to load from another MVC project. I have added the UserControls projects to the Map Route parameters so it 'should' be looking there.

I started off using Ninject in both projects but it was coming back with the following error:

> The partial view 'UserDetails' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.

If I remove the Ninject stuff from the userControls project it loads the correct controller method but fails due to requiring ninject to access the model.

Is there a way of either keeping Ninject in the 2nd project or using the bindings from the first project in the second?

**Updated:**

I have two applications in ASP.NET MVC that are different projects in the same solution. I am using Ninject in both projects.  I am trying to load a partial view from one project into another using

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("UserDetails", "UserDetails", ...}
```

When I do this and place a break point on the constructor of the UserDetails controller it gets hit. The constructor has the following lines of code:

```
 _guestDetailsField = guestDetailsField;
 _guest = guest;
 _bookingSelection = bookingSelection;
```

When I debug past these I get a "No Source Available" page, and when I continue the page is loaded with the error message given above.

Comment: I should add when ninject is in the usercontrols project the constructor for the controller (taking abstract model instances as parameters) is hit, so its still finding the right place.

Comment: I am reading your question for the third time and still do not understand anything from it. Giving up. Hopefully you will provide some more details.

Comment: Ok, maybe explaining what you don't understand will help. But I will add some more information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share views across applications. In fact you can but you will have to write a custom [virtual path provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx) which could be quite a lot of work. For example you may take a look at the [following article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) which illustrates a custom provider which allows embedding Razor views into separate assemblies and reusing them across multiple MVC applications.

Comment: But when I took the ninject stuff out of the "UserControls" project and debugged through it it was working, it only fell down because I couldn't access the data with ninject.